# First Derivative The slope at the sample points

Tags: interpolation, derived-functors

I am trying to implement an interpolation function in C# and one of the parameter is an array of 4 elements, which should contains first derivative of the slope at the sample 4 points.  I am not a math expert and I have been google for a while without success.  These are the arrays.  Thank you for any help.

```
Points Values
1.0    3.2
2.0    3.4
3.0    3.6
4.0    3.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is the slope and this varies linearly, the function will be quadratic. Since $$y'=3+0.2 x$$ then $$y=a + 3x+0.1 x^2$$

Comment: Thank you, still not clear but is my fault.

Comment: @Doro. At any point along a curve, the slope of the tangent is equal to the derivative of the function. When you have the expression of the derivative, integrate it to get the function. Is it any better ? If not, just post. Cheers :-)

Comment: Can you suggest me a very easy and basic tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand, the values correspond to the second derivative of the function and it is clearly linear; so, the function is a cubic, say $$y=a +b x+c x^2+d x^3$$ $$y'=b+2c x+3dx^2$$ $$y''=2c+3dx$$ From the table, or plotting the values, you have $c=\frac32$, $d=\frac{2}{30}$. Now, the problem is : which $a,b$ to be used ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am looking for first derivative and not second derivative.  This is part of the function that I am trying to implement.  Summary:
Create a hermite cubic spline interpolation from an unsorted set of (x,y) value pairs and their slope (first derivative).

Comment: You wrote *first derivative of the slope* !

Comment: Well yes.  I am not sure what you meant with your first answer.  Anyway, how can I get 4 slops from the above values?